# Function should calculate an average but produces no output

Tags: visual-c++

I have a list of students and I need to display, for each student, the average time he/she takes to study 3 classes. All those times are recorded so it's just a simple averaging of three integers that I'm trying to do for each student. But the function produces no output.

This is what I used in main.cpp to call on the function:

```
cout << "Average days to complete a course, by student ID:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
{
classRoster.printAverageDaysInCourse(classRoster.getStudent(i)->getStudentID());
}
cout << endl;
```

And this is the actual printAverageDaysInCourse:

```
void Roster::printAverageDaysInCourse(string studentID) const {
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
if (classRosterArray[i]->getStudentID() == studentID) {
found = true;
const int* daysInCourse = classRosterArray[i]->getDaysInCourse();
double avgDaysInCourse = (daysInCourse[0] + daysInCourse[1] + daysInCourse[2]) / 3;
cout << "Average number of days in course for student with ID " << studentID << ": " << avgDaysInCourse << endl;
break;
}
}
if (!found) {
cout << "Error: Student with ID " << studentID << " not found in roster." << endl;
}
}
```

So I'm trying to average (daysInCourse[0] + daysInCourse[1] + daysInCourse[2]) / 3 but it doesn't work. The output shows "Average days to complete a course, by student ID:" but nothing else.

Is there something wrong with the way I wrote printAverageDaysInCourse or the way I call it? Or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Perhaps `numStudents` is zero or negative, so the loop that's supposed to call `printAverageDaysInCourse` never runs.

Comment: That was it, Igor. :) numStudents was 0. Thank you so much for pointing that possibility out. The code works now.